# Display CONCAT() from second table if not NULL

Tags: mysql, null, left-join, concatenation

So, I've got a database that stores user data in its own table for use by anything that may need it. Then, a projects table with a column to identify the user assigned to the project, but it's nullable (in case someone hasn't been assigned it yet). When I need to to display the "last, first" from the users table if the assigned user ID isn't NULL.

Here's what I have for if all the projects have a user assign:

```
SELECT p.name, CONCAT(u.lastName, ', ', u.firstName) AS user, p.dueDate 
FROM projects p, users u 
WHERE p.uid = u.id 
ORDER BY p.id DESC;
```

This results in no results when the `p.uid` is `NULL`, and I need it to still display the project, just leaving the field blank.  Here's a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cff66/1

I've tried using `CONCAT_WS()` (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cff66/2) and `LEFT JOIN` (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cff66/3), with identical results:

```
Name   | User      | Due Date
---------------------------------------------------
Proj 4 | Doe, John | October, 24 2014 00:00:00+0000
Proj 2 | Doe, John | October, 27 2014 00:00:00+0000
```

What I need it to show is:

```
Name   | User      | Due Date
----------------------------------------------------
Proj 5 |           | December, 25 2014 00:00:00+0000
Proj 4 | Doe, John | October, 24 2014 00:00:00+0000
Proj 3 |           | October, 30 2014 00:00:00+0000
Proj 2 | Doe, John | October, 27 2014 00:00:00+0000
Proj 1 |           | October, 22 2014 00:00:00+0000
```

Anyone have an idea on how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a `Left Join` instead of your implied `INNER JOIN` since you want ALL records from `projects` table and any records that can be found in the `users` table. Also, you'll need a `CASE` statement (or `if` statement if that is more your style) to make the `user` `null` when `u.id` is `null`.

```
SELECT p.name, 
    CASE WHEN u.id IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(u.lastName, ', ', u.firstName) ELSE NULL END AS user, 
    p.dueDate 
FROM 
    projects p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users u on p.uid = u.id 
ORDER BY p.id DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, `left join` is the way to go, but you used the wrong table in it. The `left join` should be applied to the table that may be "missing" rows, `users` in your case.  In order to handle the case when nobody is assigned to the project, you can use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT          p.name, 
                CASE WHEN u.id IS NOT NULL 
                     THEN CONCAT(u.lastName, ', ', u.firstName) 
                END AS user, 
                p.dueDate 
FROM            projects p
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON p.uid = u.id 
ORDER BY        p.id DESC;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cff66/7/0)**

Comment: I want to mark yours correct to, for the extra information you provided.  Sorry, but thank you for the help. ^^